# Why are my .txt files printed when I double-click them?

Tags: notepad

My Text files (`.txt`) are not opening. Instead, they are printing as the default command when I double-click on any file.

I realized that the print command is default now and open is not the default command.

How do i change it back?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open up a folder and then go to the menu:

> Tools > Folder Options > File Types

Go down to the TXT extension and then click the **Advanced** button for the **Edit File Type** dialog:

[image: Edit File Type dialog]

#### If you are missing the open action

> To create a new **`open`** action, take the following steps:
>
> 1. Click **New**. A *New Action* dialog will pop up
> 2. For *Action*, enter `open`
> 3. For *Application used to perform action*, enter
>    `"C:\WINDOWS\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1"`
> 4. Click **OK**
>
> [image: New Action dialog]
>
> (Adjust the program file path as necessary if you prefer opening with another text editor.)

In the **Edit File Type** dialog:

- Select **open** under the Actions list
- Click **Set Default**
- Click **OK**
- Close out the Folder Options

This should now set back the default action of double-clicking on a `.txt` to open instead of printing.

Comment: Actually the open command was not there, but i created it with similar settings of print command and set it default and its working now

Comment: Edit the answer to contain the filepath and other settings and i will accept it

Answer (score 2):

You cloud try to right-click on it in a Windows explorer and check if the popup menu entry "right click on it" is there.

If it is, you should then be able to select a program, use Notepad and select "always use this".

[image: open with dialog]

Otherwise, there are some ways to restore [default association in Windows XP](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/tips/xp_easy_file.htm)

Comment: The problem is that the .txt files are printing by default and not opening up as they used to/should. It isn't about being opened up by a different program.